# Does python regex follow general to specific matching?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
test1|test123
```

This only matches test1 but not test123 -  should I specify more general one first? Like `test123|test1`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in effect X|Y in regex world means X or (not X and Y) applied to each character. So test1|test123 will never match test123 because it’s already matched to test1.

Answer (score 0):

```
stri = "abcd"
regex1 = "(?P<group1>ab)|(?P<group2>cd)"
regex2 = "(?P<group1>ab).*(?P<group2>cd)"
y = re.match(regex1,stri)
if y:
    if y.group("group1"):
        print y.group("group1")
    if y.group("group2"):
        print y.group("group2")
```

The first regex (regex1) will only match group1 beacuse the y instance can take only one regex match from both the case, and obviously it will take the first match. The second (regex2) can match both group because that will be a single match object for both group1 and group2.

If you want to capture both groups with an '|' operator itself, then you can do it like

```
regex1 = re.compile("(?P<group1>ab)|(?P<group2>cd)")
for y in regex1.finditer(stri):
    if y.group("group1"):
        print y.group("group1")
    if y.group("group2"):
        print y.group("group2")
```